# Gaming.SE Minecraft skin

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

To celebrate [Fosco](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/2263/fosco)'s moment of madness that lead to me really owning Minecraft, I've quickly made a Gaming/Minecraft skin for you to use.

> [image: Heart gaming skin.]
>
> ### [Download the skin.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWOlE.png)

---

The skin is available also in [.xcf version](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1164414/Artwork/SO/Gaming%20Minecraft%20Skin.xcf), should you want to tweak it (say, move the heart to the back, reduce the heart's opacity a bit so you can see the shirt texture, and/or adding other emblems, [like I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwp6F.png)).